# Why has TabListener been deprecated?

Tags: android

In Android 5 (API level 21) the [ActionBar.TabListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.TabListener.html) has been deprecated. Why? What are we supposed to use instead? Does this mean that action tabs as a UI element have been deprecated in general or is there a new way to implement them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Several ActionBar-related classes have been deprecated in favor of [Toolbar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar.html), which is a generalization of ActionBar. Some extra reading  [here](https://chris.banes.me/2014/10/17/appcompat-v21/).

Answer (score 6):

Look this example [SlidingTabsBasics](http://developer.android.com/samples/SlidingTabsBasic/index.html)
If you need more info - check [Google I/O sources](https://github.com/google/iosched)

Answer (score 4):

As of Android 5.0 a tab style layout is best created by using the newly introduced design library by google. The easiest way to implement it (and not having to rewrite everything) is by using `TabLayout` in conjunction with a `ViewPager`.

I was able to reuse most of my code and it took me approx. 30 minutes to go through everything until I had a working `TabLayout` displaying my existing fragments.

You can find a very good tutorial here:
https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Google-Play-Style-Tabs-using-TabLayout

If you want more info on the design library this is a pretty good summary imo:
https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Design-Support-Library