# Tabbed Activity Template ActionBar.TabListener deprecated

Tags: android, deprecated

I am using the Tabbed Activity (that includes swipes and tabs) and when I was looking at the generated code, noticed that "ActionBarActivity" is deprecated. So I went online [android docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.html) and show that I should use "AppCompatActivity" insted, I changed the extending class from ActionBarActivity to AppCompatActivity and there was no problem. However, there is another deprecated interface and that is ActionBar.TabListener. What should I use instead of this interface ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26669857/why-has-tablistener-been-deprecated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch to toolbar much easier to work with you can use pagerslidingtabstrip and link it with your viewpager.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What do you think I should use instead the ActionBar.TabListener in order to respond to user's swipe/taps on tabbed activity ? :)

Comment: https://github.com/jpardogo/PagerSlidingTabStrip -- Include this in your gradle build file and set toolbar as your actionbar ie toolbar  /* setSupportActionBar(toolbar); */ and then set the viewpager to that pagerslidingtabstrip that you imported. /*http://pastebin.com/uk4hw4Zr */ take a look at a code from one of my apps for its implementation